# Ubuntu Server 12.04 on IBM x3300 M4 - Grub is not installing

Tags: grub2, lenovo, ibm

Ubuntu on IBM/Lenovo x3300 M4

Everything went fine till Grub installation stage. Not completed the installation with a fatal error massage. 
We are using RAID Zero with 3 HDDs. 
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

load default setting and restore setting on BIOS, install ubuntu. after finish, boot using IBM Server Guide CD/DVD and set to RAID default.

Comment: How does this help with a grub error?